# InstallShield, update files that were modified

Tags: installation, installshield

I'm using InstallShield in order to create an installer/updater for an application (Basic MSI). I have installed an application (version 1) with the installer and then manually modified some files. The problem is that when I upgraded this application to version 2 with a new installer, it didn't overwrite these manually modified files. I got this message in the installation log file:

> Won't Overwrite;  Won't patch;    Existing file is unversioned but
>   modified

For properly overwritten files I get this in the log file:

> Overwrite;    Won't patch;    Existing file is unversioned and unmodified -
>   hash doesn't match source file

Question: is it possible to automatically overwrite these manually modified files during the upgrade process? Is there a setting in InstallShield that lets me do this?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the [file versioning rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599%28VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) prevent Windows Installer from overwriting the files. Basically, when modifying your source files you should also increase their version (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RemoveFile table. You can access this from the DIRECT EDITOR of Installshield IDE.
Configure RemoveFile Table to remove the modified files.